# Cannot open properties for arrive source in Anylogic

Tags: null, anylogic, event-loop

I'm unable to open the properties for the arrive source. I get this error "Event Loop Exception Null". In the problems console the description is that there's an unresolved reference being surname in the arrive source. I have already removed the parameters and database where surname was being used but still get the same error. [image: Error of source]

I also tried to restart anylogic multiple times but that didn't work.

Comment: Delete the block and drag in a new one, then set it up as before. You likely used a dbase reference that AL stored in the background and now cannot find anymore

Comment: I'm also unable to delete it. doesn't allow me to delete it after i right click the block

Comment: then there is something fundamentally broken with your installation. Does it work with new models from scratch? Try to do some root-cause analysis yourself to hone into the problem :)